# How to make a "Low state CPU" persistent?

Tags: cpu, persistent, low-power

I would like to lower my cpu power (at 50%),

For doing this I executed the following command:

`powercfg -setacvalueindex SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMAX 50`

`powercfg.exe -setactive SCHEME_CURRENT`

It's okay, but unfortunately only for a short time,
after about 30 minutes, it back to 100%

How could I make this change persistent?



***Edit :*** The "manual" harrymc's way is just another way to do the same,
so my problem is still here.
(the edited configuration is not persistent and backs to 100% alone for an unknow reason)

Maybe there is another way to limit the power allocate for the software ?
I already set affinity to only one core but software fails to work properly like this (only one core was working at 100%).
And I would like ALL core working at 50%.

Comment: Still no solution... So my temporary solution will be to loop the command every 10 minutes in .bat

Comment: Is this a company-owned/managed computer, perhaps?

Comment: no that's my personnal desktop computer

Answer (score 0):

This setting should stick :

- Run *Start > Power Options > Change advanced power settings*
- Scroll down and open the branch "Processor power management"
- Click "Maximum processor state" and set it to `50`
- Click OK.

To test, reboot and verify that the value has not changed.

Comment: Thank you,
but I already try to make this "manually" like you said,
and it had the same effect :
backs to 100% after ~30 minutes (or after a reboot)

Comment: That's not normal. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @redscreen - Verify your power configuration isn’t changing. Your processor isn’t going to use less power if it’s running slower, or specifically, if it does there won’t be a significant difference

Comment: @redscreen: Where do you see the 100% ?

Comment: I see 100% in : " Task Manager > Performance "
And also hear the fan speed up,
that's the reason for I reduced the Maximum processor state...

Comment: @redscreen - Reducing the processor state isn’t guaranteed to reduce the fan speed.

Comment: Also, I wonder if the 100% you see is out of the 50% CPU that's allocated ...

Comment: @Ramhound :  in this case it reduces it, so I think it's the good way, but to improve...

Comment: @harrymc :  windows integrity checked and ok  ---  CTRL+MAj+ESC > Performance > Processor % (top left)